# Is there a way to limit the size of avro files when writing from kafka via hdfs connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-flink, apache-kafka-connect

Currently we used the Flink `FsStateBackend` checkpointing and set `fileStateSizeThreshold` to limit the size of data written to avro/json files on HDFS to 128MB. Also closing files after a certain delay in checkpoint actions.

Since we are not using advanced Flink features in in a new project we want to use Kafka Streaming with the `Kafka Connect HDFS Connector` to write messages directly to hdfs (without spinning up Flink)

However I cannot find if there are options to limit the filesize of the hdfs files from the kafka connector, except maybe `flush.size` which seem to limit the # of records.

If there are no settings on the connector, how do people manage the filesizes from streaming data on hdfs in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no file size option, only time based rotation and flush size. You can set a large flush size, which you never think you'll reach, then a time based rotation will do a best-effort partitioning of large files into date partitions (we've been able to get 4GB output files per topic partition within an hour directory from Connect)

Personally, I suggest additional tools such as Hive, Pig, DistCp, Flink/Spark, depending on what's available, and not all at once, running in an Oozie job to "compact" these streaming files into larger files.

See [my comment here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues/271#issuecomment-364978582)

---

Before Connect, there was Camus, which is now Apache Gobblin. Within that project, it offers the ideas of compaction and late event processing + Hive table creation

---

The general answer here is that you have a designated "hot landing zone" for streaming data, then you periodically archive it or "freeze" it (which brings out technology names like Amazon Glacier/Snowball & [Snowplow](https://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2013/05/30/dealing-with-hadoops-small-files-problem/))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do like these solutions, but I'd really lie for refrain from adding additional processing steps for archiving. Especially since the sink will become part of a 'as a service pipeline' where we can spin up different kafka clusters for different tenants. I really would like just to use a single consumer/sink that will bucket incoming data either after a certain window or size like this Flink BucketingSink: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.html

Comment: Alright, well, use Flink if that's the feature you want, then

Comment: I could, but I just wanted to check wether there was an option where I could just use a kafka connector without starting a flink cluster. It seems wasteful and potentially unnecessary overhead to run flink just as a data sink for a kafka topic

Comment: The option doesn't exist in the Confluent Connectors. You might be able to find some other one that accomplishes this, but creating files based on size seems to have two edge cases to me when a new file is made. For example, Kafka records could range in size and arrival time, so if you get a record from 2 hours ago, would it make a new file or be appended to one? If that previously written file is over the size limit, you'll still have small files. If you get record that spans the threshold of the "current file", would it start a new file, or append there, if new, then there's small files